# Display "Washed Out" After Upgrade to Debian Squeeze?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, display

After upgrading from Debian Lenny to Debian Squeeze and opening XFCE, i find that the colors appear "washed out" or "too light."  On top of that, the screen resolution defaults to 1440x900 which is inappropriately big for the monitor i'm using.  I suspect this has something to do with xorg & hal misidentifying my hardware.  I can fix the resolution with xrandr but how do i fix the color?

Running on various server class video cards including ATI ES1000 through a Black Box KVM over Cat5 system.  I suspect the KVM system is what's confusing xorg and hal.

Answer (score 3):

The display's gamma settings need to be calibrated for better display.  A tool like GAMMApage can help tune the colors of the display.  GAMMApage in particular, then applies an `xgamma` command to your X startup scripts to have those settings applied at every login.

http://freecode.com/projects/gammapage